# Allowed memory size exhausted while using Yii datatables

Tags: php, yii, datatables, yii-extensions

I am using [Yii Datatables](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/edatatables) extension.

My table contains only single row and when I try to open the page that runs query it breaks with following error:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes)
```

The page works fine when there is no data in the table i.e when I truncate the table, but as I enter even when record then I get above error.

From above error it is evident that it is not memory issue because it only tried to allocate 16384 bytes out of 134217728 bytes available for php process.

What could be the cause of that?

Comment: which log is it? is it php or mysql log?

Comment: No MySQL log is generated for that request. Apache log is as follows: 
child pid 10707 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Comment: is it same without using the extension too ?

Comment: It tried to allocate 16384 when it failed as the memory limit was exhausted, so this is indeed a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase memory size by increasing default value of

> max_allowed_packet = 30M -(this value is what you need to increase)

in my.ini file of db config file.

you can find this file (for xampp) by clicking in xampp mysql config button.

**if this doesn't solve please try this.**

increase amount of memory script in php.ini file

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit

> memory_limit=500M

Answer (score 0):

write this in top of your file php, to upgrade memory limit

```
$old = ini_set('memory_limit', '8192M');
```